# Am I looking for an "After Update" event or something else?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to make a database for paperwork for a summer camp.  Right now I have a form setup that has a combo box with the the children's name in the header.  And I have three tabs separating the different papers they need to turn in (medical, permissions, etc).  I have the combo box working, sort of.  When I click on it I have it showing the list of names, but I don't seem to have it connected to the underlying table, so it could show the records.  The records are all a mix of checkboxes (yes/no) and text boxes (for additional comments).  Does the combo box need to have an After Update event, or would it be in another event?  I've tried copying some code that I've found, but it hasn't seemed to work.  Right now there should be some information that shows up that I've already entered directly into the table, but other fields I know are blank.

My goal is to be able to select a child from the combo box and pull up their records and edit information as needed.  I'm a real beginner with coding, but I think it's something that would lead me to a solution here.  I've been across a variety of forms today and nothing seems to have worked for me yet.  I'm also just beginning to learn access so I'm only starting to know the kinds of questions to ask.  Any help or suggestions would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In an Access form, there are either **bound** or **unbound** controls. Bound means table fields are connected and unbound means there are no table field connection. The same can be said about bound and unbound forms where bound has a whole table connected to form and unbound does not. If you enter Design View, you will either see a field name in textbox or "Unbound" written in textbox. For checkboxes you cannot tell unless you enter its Property Sheet \ Data tab \ Control Source.

From your explanation, you seem to refer to a search box. This would be an unbound form as no data should be tied to it. Your header of Student's Name seems to be a bound textbox of student name. Search boxes have an AfterUpdate event built in either as a macro or VBA that searches a record that matches the selection of the drop down:

Macro:

```
Search Record
Object Type: Form
Object Name: YourFormName
Record: First
Where Condition: ="[ID] = " & Str(Nz([Screen].[ActiveControl],0))
```

VBA:

```
DoCmd.SearchForRecord acDataForm, "yourFormName", acFirst, "[ID] = " & Forms!YourFormNam!DropDownField
```

Please note you can create a search box simply by placing a new combo box on the form and following the **Wizard** all the way through. The outcome of this will be an AfterUpdate event macro as listed above. You must have canceled the wizard before finishing to have an unbound combo box with no functionality.

Comment: This is where I think I may have gone wrong.  I started with a simple columnar form to enter information into a table [Camp Haven Papers].  It looked like a regular spreadsheet.  Then I started receiving more paperwork so I made a new, more complete form for everything I needed [CompletePaperwork].  I added the old fields to it, but added 3 additional tabs.  I just wanted to be able to pull up the existing record, and then add the new information to it.  I added the VBA code to the combo box, and it didn't seem to do anything.